# Exceuting a simple assembly code in C++ without it being in a function

Tags: c++, hook, inline-assembly

I'm trying to write a trampoline hook to some win32 api function, when I write the JMP instruction to the start of the original function I want it to jump to a codecave instead of calling a function.

The original function start looks like this in OllyDBG:

```
PUSH 14
MOV EAX, 12345678
...
```

And I patch it to:

```
JMP 87654321
NOP
NOP
```

The address of the following function:

```
int HookFunc(int param)
{
    DoStuff(param);
    return ExecuteOriginal(param);
}
```

ExceuteOriginal looks like this:

```
unsigned long address = AddressOfOriginalFunction + 7;

int ExceuteOriginal(int param)
{
    __asm
    {
        PUSH 0x14
        MOV EAX, 0x12345678
        JMP address
    }
}
```

Which executes the overridden code and jumps to the original function right after the patched code. The problem is that since it's a function, it'll mess up the stack because the caller should clean it up and the function instead of return, jumps to another function's code. And I guess that's why the program crashes.

Is there a way using Visual C++ compiler to place the assembly code in the code section of the program without having it being inside a function? That way I can jump there, execute whatever, and return back without the risk of messing up the stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution: [`__declspec(naked)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5w10wxs.aspx)**

> For functions declared with the naked attribute, the compiler generates code without prolog and epilog code. You can use this feature to write your own prolog/epilog code sequences using inline assembler code.

Example:

```
__declspec( naked ) int ExceuteOriginal(int param)
{
    __asm
    {
        PUSH 14
        MOV EAX, 0x12345678
        JMP address
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! This is exactly what I was looking for! +1 for simple solution