# IDirect3DDevice9::EndScene hook sometimes get NULL in the parameter IDirect3DDevice9

Tags: c++, directx, hook, directx-9

I made a trampoline hook for the function IDirect3DDevice9::EndScene. The codecave I modified the start if the EndScene function to jump to is this:

```
__declspec(naked) HRESULT EndScene_Hook(IDirect3DDevice9* device)
{
    ScreenCapture::Capture(device);

    __asm
    {
        PUSH 0x14
        MOV EAX, 0x718E6478
        JMP address
    }
}
```

The problem is that sometimes `device` is NULL, why is that? if I add a small condition like this:

```
if(device != NULL)
    ScreenCapture::Capture(device);
```

Everything works as intended with no errors.

What possibly can be the reason for this function to receive `device` as NULL? This is a member function of the object `IDirect3DDevice9`, it shouldn't be possible to call it like this `EndScene(NULL)` because it always called from it's object (e.g pDevice->EndScene()).

Answer (score 1):

Using `__declspec(naked)` tells the compiler not to emit a prologue or an epilogue for the function. In the prologue the compiler would normally emit the instructions necessary for it to be able later access arguments to the function that are passed on the stack. Since your code references the argument `device` the code the compiler emits to access this argument doesn't work and ends up accessing an unpredictable value in memory. One of the more likely possibilities is that ends up accessing the the first argument of the function that called it, and this is why it may appear to work from time to time. However you can't depend on this.

You should really write a function like this entirely in assembly. You're going to need to if you want it you want to hook 64-bit code anyways.

Comment: I intentionally used `__declspec(naked)` because I insert the unconditional jump to this function at the start of `EndScene`, and I dont want the compiler to insert epilogue/prologue so it won't mess up the stack and I'll be able to read the parameter properly. Shouldn't the compiler always prepare the parameter on the stack at this point? And if not, you have any suggestions on what method to use so I can receive the parameter safely? I'm not interested at 64 bit applications at the moment.

Comment: The compiler always prepares to access the parameter on the stack, unless you tell it not to. You told it not to. You can receive the parameter safely by writing the function entirely in assembly.

Comment: But the point is to receive the parameter already prepared for the real function, here take a look at this question and see what I mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24277471/exceuting-a-simple-assembly-code-in-c-without-it-being-in-a-function

Comment: Jonathon Reinhart's answer to that question assumed you didn't need to access the parameter because your example code in that question didn't access the parameter. By using inline assembly and `_declspec(naked)` you're telling the compiler you know how to generate code better than the compiler. If as a result the compiler generates code that doesn't work, then it's your fault. You can't blame the compiler.

Comment: But I wanted to use the code generated by the compiler for the function EndScene and insert a small piece of code into the start of that function. What I actual want to do is not to create a function, is to insert a codecave into an existing function. Should I write epilogue/prologue for that too? If so what will be the point of them?

Answer (score 0):

Calling it from a NULL object is undefined behaviour. Undefined behaviour includes "The hook I wrote sometimes recieves NULL". Whatever progam you're hooking is clearly just somewhat bugged. Or your hook is bugged.

Comment: But what can possibly explain why sometimes it's NULL and sometimes it's the correct pointer? How can the compiler will allow to compile code like this `(*(NULL)).EndScene()`? Or more corretly, why hasn't it thrown an null pointer exception at runtime in the original program?

Comment: C++ does not have null pointer exceptions. The behaaviour is undefined. That includes "Calling the proper function pointer with NULL as `this`."

Comment: But then it should crash or something no? Or popup Access violation reading location?