# Why does an EndScene hook take an argument?

Tags: c++, directx, hook

According to the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174375(v=vs.85).aspx), EndScene takes no arguments.

But I noticed when people hook EndScene, their hooked EndScene function takes a `IDirect3DDevice9* device` argument. For example: [IDirect3DDevice9::EndScene hook sometimes get NULL in the parameter IDirect3DDevice9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24969485/) The person asking this question has an `IDirect3DDevice9* device` argument for EndScene. Why is this?

Here is a second example: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=9HqJ3Wzz

Comment: They seem to be taking the object that is having `EndScene` called on it so that they can capture what's being drawn before `EndScene` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, member functions are implemented like regular functions, but take an additional first argument that is the pointer to the object : the `this` pointer. When you hook a function, it usually involve using the raw address of the actual function, thus the easiest way (more like, the only sane way) is to handle this hooked function as a standard C-style function, and artificially add the `this` pointer first argument.

**EDIT:** The calling convention might indeed be a problem as pointed out, but it works for `IDirect3DDevice9` and similar because they have their methods declared as `__stdcall`.

Comment: If I understood correctly, in thiscall convention, parameters are pushed right-to-left. Either caller or callee is responsible for cleaning up the stack – depending if variable number of arguments is being used. A this pointer is passed in the ECX register. If the this pointer is in the ECX register, why would it be passed as an argument? Stdcall expects all arguments to be pushed onto the stack but the this pointer is in a register.

Comment: This might be a better example than the first one: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=9HqJ3Wzz

Comment: @RandyWeber That's a good point. It works in this case because all the COM style interfaces like Direct3D have their methods declared as `__stdcall`.

Comment: Ah thanks. This was driving me insane so I'm glad I finally got it.

Comment: @RandyWeber Also, I never tried but it might work for a normal method if the C-style function is declared as `__thiscall`. And for x64 it doesn't matter, all the conventions are the same.